# When I use mysqldump with the --ignore-table-data option, I get an "unknown variable" error

Tags: mysql, mariadb

The "[--ignore-table-data](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-dumpmysqldump/)" option can be used to exclude the data from one or more specific tables in the dump.

```
mysqldump -u root -p mydatabase --ignore-table-data=mydatabase.excludedtable > mybackup.sql
```

When I run it, I get an error:

> mysqldump: [ERROR] unknown variable
> 'ignore-table-data=mydatabase.excludedtable'.

Without that --ignore-table option, the dump is generated:

```
mysqldump -u root -p mydatabase > mybackup.sql
```

Configuration:
Win 11, Wampserver
MariaDB 10.6.5
MySQL 8.0.27

Comment: So are you doing this to MySQL or mariaDB?

Comment: MySQL's mysqldump does not have the `--ignore-table-data` option. This is an option implemented only in MariaDB since MariaDB forked. You should consider MariaDB and MySQL to be totally different products, because there are many such features implemented in one or the other since they split.